# Merging many json files into one by merging it into a common object

Tags: json, jq

I have many json files of such format:

sample `file1`:

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "Node",
      "value": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

sample `file2`:

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "version",
      "value": "11.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

etc.

I need to merge all of them to one json file, eg.

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "Node",
      "value": "test"
    },
    {
      "name": "version",
      "value": "11.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone please provide a solution with jq?

Answer (score 17):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -s '{ attributes: map(.attributes[0]) }' file*.json
```

- `-s` (`--slurp`) - instead of running the filter for each *JSON* object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.

Sample output:

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "Node",
      "value": "test"
    },
    {
      "name": "version",
      "value": "11.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In contrast to [RomanPerekhrest's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433687), this will allow you merge the target field without remaking the entire object:

```
jq -s '.[0].attributes = [.[].attributes | add] | .[0]' file*.json
```

This returns the entirety of the first json file with the `.attributes` from all the others concatenated together.

Answer (score 1):

Another `jq` variant, that doesn't involve slurp, but with `inputs` and `reduce`

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; reduce ($in|keys_unsorted)[] as $k (.;
         .[$k] += $in[$k]))'  file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsonmerge](https://pypi.org/project/jsonmerge/)

```
>>> base = {
...         "foo": 1,
...         "bar": [ "one" ],
...      }

>>> head = {
...         "bar": [ "two" ],
...         "baz": "Hello, world!"
...     }

>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> from jsonmerge import merge
>>> result = merge(base, head)

>>> pprint(result, width=40)
{'bar': ['two'],
 'baz': 'Hello, world!',
 'foo': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the JSON documents to TOML using `yq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), and then back from TOML to JSON using `tomlq` (from the same `yq` distribution):

```bsh
$ yq -t '.' file1 file2 | tomlq .
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "Node",
      "value": "test"
    },
    {
      "name": "version",
      "value": "11.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works because `yq -t` creates the concatenation of the two TOML documents

```
[[attributes]]
name = "Node"
value = "test"
```

and

```
[[attributes]]
name = "version"
value = "11.1"
```

Together, according to the rules of [TOML](https://toml.io/en/), this happens to be equivalent of the JSON document that you are looking to create (by virtue of `attributes` being an array).  So when `tomlq` converts it back to JSON, it does the right thing.

---

You can do the equivalent transformations using the `yj` utility (from https://github.com/sclevine/yj) too:

```bsh
yj -tj < <( cat <( yj -jt <file1 ) <( yj -jt <file2 ) )
```

or, without the process substitutions and the `cat`,

```bsh
{ yj -jt <file1; yj -jt <file2; } | yj -tj
```

It turns out you could do the same type of round-trip via Hashicorp's HCL format too, using `yj -jc` and `yj -cj` in place of `yj -jt` and `yj -tj` respectively.